# Payload for an Odata Service

Tags: api, odata, sapui5

Are there any steps/procedure to figure out the payload for a given odata service?
I currently have a whitelisted odata service 
[Process Purchase Orders](https://api.sap.com/shell/discover/contentpackage/SAPS4HANACloud/api/API_PURCHASEORDER_PROCESS_SRV)

I am unable to figure out how the payload will look like for `A_PurchaseOrder`.

Whatever payload I keep on trying, I am always getting unable to parse XML Stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the request and see it.For A_PurchaseOrder

```
 {
 "PurchaseOrder": "string",
 "CashDiscount1Days": 999,
 "CashDiscount2Days": 999,
 "NetPaymentDays": 999,
 "CashDiscount1Percent": 99.999,
 "CashDiscount2Percent": 99.999,
 "PurchaseOrderDate": "/Date(1492041600000)/",
 "ValidityStartDate": "/Date(1492041600000)/",
 "ValidityEndDate": "/Date(1492041600000)/",
 "CreationDate": "/Date(1492041600000)/",
 "to_PurchaseOrderItem":[{
         "PurchaseOrder": "string",
         "OrderQuantity": 9999999999.999,
         "OrderPriceUnitToOrderUnitNmrtr": 99999,
         "OrdPriceUnitToOrderUnitDnmntr": 99999,
         "NetPriceAmount": 999999999.999,
         "NetPriceQuantity": 99999,
         "PurchaseOrderItem": "string",
         "OverdelivTolrtdLmtRatioInPct": 99.9,
         "UnderdelivTolrtdLmtRatioInPct": 99.9,
         "ItemNetWeight": 9999999999.999,
         "ItemVolume": 9999999999.999,
         "to_AccountAssignment":[{
                 "PurchaseOrder": "string",
                 "PurchaseOrderItem": "string",
                 "AccountAssignmentNumber": "string",
                 "SettlementReferenceDate": "/Date(1492041600000)/",
                 "Quantity": 9999999999.999,
                 "MultipleAcctAssgmtDistrPercent": 99.9,
                 "PurgDocNetAmount": 99999999999.999
             }],

         "to_PurchaseOrderPricingElement": [{
                 "PurchaseOrder": "string",
                 "ConditionQuantity": 99999,
                 "ConditionToBaseQtyNmrtr": 9999999999,
                 "ConditionToBaseQtyDnmntr": 9999999999,
                 "PurchaseOrderItem": "string",
                 "PricingDocument": "string",
                 "FactorForConditionBasisValue": 3.14,
                 "PricingDocumentItem": "string",
                 "PricingProcedureStep": "string",
                 "PricingProcedureCounter": "string"
             }],

         "to_ScheduleLine":[{
                 "PurchasingDocument": "string",
                 "ScheduleLineCommittedQuantity": 9999999999.999,
                 "PurchasingDocumentItem": "string",
                 "ScheduleLine": "string",
                 "ScheduleLineDeliveryDate": "/Date(1492041600000)/",
                 "ScheduleLineOrderQuantity": 9999999999.999,
                 "ScheduleLineDeliveryTime": "PT15H51M04S",
                 "SchedLineStscDeliveryDate": "/Date(1492041600000)/"
             }]
         }
         ]
 }
```

Comment: I have tried this already. Still no avail. Posting a payload always generates a 500 Status code for me, with message "The requested service  is not supported by entity ~A_PURCHASEORDER"

As far as I know we get this error if CREATE_ENTITY is not implemented. However since this is a whitelisted service, it must be definitely implemented right?

Comment: And your answer is actually the response. And not the request. Kindly be clear before answering.

Comment: @DibyaRanjan I have edited my answer.It should work.

Comment: After changing the "string" to proper values, now I am getting ""In the context of Data Services an unknown internal server error occurred".

Comment: Currently I am trying to post this https://pastebin.com/CrFkj05t

But I am getting "Schedule line has been created automatically for item 00120."

And If I remove the Schedule Line Part, I get some unknown error occurred.

Comment: I have added another answer with..scheduleline etc are empty

Answer (score 0):

try this payload.

```
    {
 "PurchaseOrder": "0120",
 "CashDiscount1Days": 999,
 "CashDiscount2Days": 999,
 "NetPaymentDays": 999,
 "CashDiscount1Percent": 99.999,
 "CashDiscount2Percent": 99.999,
 "PurchaseOrderDate": "/Date(1492041600000)/",
 "ValidityStartDate": "/Date(1492041600000)/",
 "ValidityEndDate": "/Date(1492041600000)/",
 "CreationDate": "/Date(1492041600000)/",
 "to_PurchaseOrderItem":[{
         "PurchaseOrder": "0120",
         "OrderQuantity": 9999999999.999,
         "OrderPriceUnitToOrderUnitNmrtr": 99999,
         "OrdPriceUnitToOrderUnitDnmntr": 99999,
         "NetPriceAmount": 999999999.999,
         "NetPriceQuantity": 99999,
         "PurchaseOrderItem": "string",
         "OverdelivTolrtdLmtRatioInPct": 99.9,
         "UnderdelivTolrtdLmtRatioInPct": 99.9,
         "ItemNetWeight": 9999999999.999,
         "ItemVolume": 9999999999.999,
         "to_AccountAssignment":[],

         "to_PurchaseOrderPricingElement": [],

         "to_ScheduleLine":[]
         }
         ]
 }
```